# Class validation for typeorm's Point object

Tags: typescript, typeorm, class-validator

I'm trying to write a [custom class validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-validation-classes) for the [Point](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities#spatial-columns) object in typeorm.

Here is my code:

```
// isPointConstraint.ts

import { ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, registerDecorator } from 'class-validator';
import { Point } from 'typeorm';


@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsPoint', async: false })
export class IsPointConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    validate(value: any, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
        if (!(value instanceof Point)) { // <- Getting error at this line
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    defaultMessage?(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): string {
        // throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
        return 'Invalid point format';
    }

}

export function IsPoint(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            constraints: [],
            validator: IsPointConstraint,
        });
    };
}
```

However I'm getting this error: `'Point' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

How to fix it? Or Should I create a different type of validation?

Comment: Yeah, Point isn't a class. You need to write a different check to check the structure of the object.

Comment: @merryweather can you please point me to some example?

Comment: How can I check if the object of type any is actually an object of type Point?